# Can someone explain this algebraic proof of the Pascal's Indentity?

Tags: combinatorics

I found this algebraic proof of the Pascal's Indentity in a book. I don't get how it was simplified. I want someone to explain the proof from step 2.

$\binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r} = \binom{n}{r}$

Proof:

$\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!((n-1)-(r-1))!} + \dfrac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-1-r)!}$

$= \dfrac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} + \dfrac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-1-r)!}$

$= \dfrac{r(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!} + \dfrac{(n-r)(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}$

$= \dfrac{r(n-1)! +(n-r)(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}$

$= \dfrac{n(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}$

$= \dfrac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$

$= \binom{n}{r}$

PS:I know it is trivial stuff but I just started learning combinatorics.

Comment: It is simply making the fractions have the same denominator in order to add them. No different to for example $\frac23+\frac14 = \frac{4\cdot2}{4\cdot3}+\frac{3\cdot1}{3\cdot4} = \frac{8}{12}+\frac{3}{12} = \frac{8+3}{12} = \frac{11}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

- $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{(r-1)!(n-r)!} =  \dfrac{r(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}$ by multiplying by $\dfrac rr$,
- $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{r!(n-1-r)!} =   \dfrac{(n-r)(n-1)!}{r!(n-r)!}$ by multiplying by $\dfrac{n-r}{n-r}$

You may want $r\not=0$ and $r\not=n$, but if either equality applies then your original  $\binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r}$ will involve $0+1$ or $1+0$, giving $1$, so not a problem